# in Bixby javascript function how to manipulate JSON after receving from server

Tags: bixby

There is some very basic thing I don't understand about how Javascript functions work that is blocking me. In this script I am retrieving JSON from an api server. I need to modify the JSON slightly so it conforms to the data type model in Bixby.

```
var http = require('http');
var console = require('console')

const baseURL = 'https://www.altbrains.com/api/news/impeachmentsage';

exports.function = function getNews () {
  let options = {
    format: 'json',
    headers: {
      'accept': 'application/json'
    },
    cacheTime: 0
  };

  var response = http.getUrl(baseURL, options);

  news = response

  image_url = news.image
  console.log("image url", image_url)

    var modify;

    modify = {
        url: image_url 
      }

    console.log('modify', modify)
    news.image = modify

  console.log ('news image', news.image)
  return response;

}
```

the value of response is correctly reported as:

```
[{"image":"https://www.altbrains.com/images/48936529373_71ff9e0e13_o.jpg","tags":"news","text":"Trump's ambassador to the EU testified on Nov. 20 that 'Yes, there was a quid pro quo.'","title":"QPQ = YES"},{"image":"https://www.altbrains.com/images/48936529373_71ff9e0e13_o.jpg","tags":["news","schedule"],"text":"The next impeachment hearings by the House Permanent Select Committee on Intelligence will be held on Dec. 3.  Enjoy a peaceful Thanksgiving!","title":"What's Next"}]
```

The log reports that news.image is undefined, which prevents me from modifying it into the format required by Bixby, which has an "{url:" slot. Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got this working:

```
var http = require('http');
var console = require('console')


const baseURL = 'https://www.altbrains.com/api/news/impeachmentsage';

exports.function = function getNews () {
  let options = {
    format: 'json',
    headers: {
      'accept': 'application/json'
    },
    cacheTime: 0
  };

  response = http.getUrl(baseURL, options);

  news = response
 // news = response[0]
  console.log('news', news)
  news.forEach(function(item, index, array) {

  image_url = news[index].image
  console.log('news story', news[index])
  console.log('news image_url', news[index].image)

   modified_url = {
     url: image_url 
      }

   news[index].image = modified_url

});

  return news;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The response is an Array with an Object inside it.
Try with `news = response[0]`